# Android Data binding missing return statement in generated code

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-databinding

```
@BindingAdapter(
    "onTimeViewClick",
    "onLocationViewClick",
    "onSetDeliveryAddressClick",
)
internal fun setSubHeaderData(
    onTimeViewClick: (() -> Unit)?,
    onLocationViewClick: (() -> Unit)?,
    onSetDeliveryAddressClick: (() -> Unit)?,
) {
    view.onTimeViewClick = onTimeViewClick
    view.onLocationViewClick = onLocationViewClick
    view.onSetDeliveryAddressClick = onSetDeliveryAddressClick
}
```

Code when called from xml

```
<ModeSelectorSubHeaderView
                    android:id="@+id/mode_selector_sub_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
                    app:onLocationViewClick="@{ () -> mainViewModel.onSetDeliveryAddressTest(mainViewModel.viewState.headerInfo) }"
                    app:onSetDeliveryAddressClick="@{ mainViewModel::onSetDeliveryAddressClick }"
                />
```

The above code works. But when I change the method called in

`app:onSetDeliveryAddressClick="@{ () -> mainViewModel.onSetDeliveryAddressClick(mainViewModel.viewState.headerInfo) }"`

it gives missing return statement error in generated code.
The code is very much identical to the call `app:onLocationViewClick`

The error:

> /XXXX/databinding/ActivityMainBindingImpl.java:849: error: missing return statement
> }
> ^
> 1 error

Answer (score 0):

Binding adapter itself can only be used with interface or abstract classes with one abstract method.
The documentation does not officially mention that it supports kotlin lambda.
You can check [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters?hl=en#custom-logic).
So Replacing kotlin lambda with the interface with one abstract method may be solve your problem.